# ../include/wx/mac/carbon/private.h:1459: error: ‘Cursor’ does not name a type

Tags: macos, wxwidgets, developer-tools, rapidsvn

I have been using RapidSVN on a Linux machine for the past few years - it has become an excellent tool for managing my source.

Yesterday my trusty Linux laptop had a couple of strokes so I decided it was time to replace it.  Today I went out and purchased a new Mac Book Pro with the flashy display and solid state drives.

Then I went hunting for an SVN tool to run on Mac.  I found that RapidSVN will run on a Mac as it was developed using wxWidgets (cross platform windowing).

So, I needed to install wxWidgets, however this doesn't come as an executable so I had to download the tar ball.  To compile I realised I don't have a compiler installed yet... so, install Xcode 4.4, then learn that doesn't install a compiler either... find the Xcode preference to install the command line tools (compiler).

So, now I have Xcode installed, a gcc compiler, and tracking back up it comes to wxWidgets.  It takes a little working out but I manage to extract the files into a directory in my home folder,  (following instructions of course), and from the 'build' folder I run the ../configure command (which seems to work) and then the 'make' command which fails:

```
In file included from ../include/wx/mac/private.h:4,
             from ../src/common/dynlib.cpp:48:
../include/wx/mac/carbon/private.h:1459: error: ‘Cursor’ does not name a type
../include/wx/mac/carbon/private.h:1488: error: ‘ClassicCursor’ does not name a type
make: *** [baselib_dynlib.o] Error 1
```

So I go hunting for a solution only to find this bug: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14536 which unfortunately indicates this is not going to be fixed.

```
Changed 10 months ago by csomor 
* status changed from new to closed
* resolution set to wontfix
```

A dismal day in the land of computers.  I am now stuck for the next 5-6 years on a computer that will never be able to compile anything using wxWidgets - I rather feel like taking it back to Apple and getting my money back.

So where to from here?  Is there a binary version of wxWidgets available?  Is there a binary version of RapidSVN available?  Should I downgrade to OSX 10.x something less than I am currently on?  Should I upgrade to unstable wxWidgets?

Comment: Why Xcode 4.4 ? Why not use the latest version (4.6.x) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting but not very understandable read. What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you're looking to use the best available version of wxWidgets under OS X, get 2.9.4 or the current svn version and build it using the Xcode version you have already with Cocoa support. If you absolutely need to continue to use Carbon (why?), either install Xcode 3, available from Apple, or get 10.6 (or 10.5) SDK in some other way and pass it as the SDK to use to configure using `--with-macosx-sdk` option as explained [in the documentation](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/docs/osx/install.txt).

Comment: Sorry, as a new Mac user I don't necessarily understand the difference between Cocoa and Carbon.

Comment: Sorry, as a new OSX user I don't necessarily understand the difference between Cocoa and Carbon.  I was attempting to compile RavipSVN because I couldn't find a binary version.  In each case the software I downloaded was the current stable version which I assumed would all work on a brand new Mac OSX.  PS I read lots of articles and documentation in order to get as far as I did - as a new OSX user (coming from Debian Linux) I understand a lot of what is required, however my last 5 years with Linux was a better experience than my first 2 weeks of OSX.  A sad reflection.

Answer (score 0):

VZ is right.  If you need to use wxWidgets 2.8 on OS X (and there are legitimate reasons for needing to do so), get the 10.6 SDK.  Copy it alongside the already installed 10.7 and/or 10.8 , and select it in the project/target's build settings.

Comment: Another case of "you should be using the same version as the developer".  I'm guessing your suggestion will work - I'm simply disappointed it's not working on my brand new Mac running all the latest stable software.

Answer (score 0):

From here I have given up trying to compile anything on my current OSX.  I am not going to downgrade or install multiple versions of different libraries in order to satisfy the lack of support for the latest current stable versions.

From here I will download and install binaries only.

Answer (score 0):

I have Mac OSX Lion and just did this:

```
brew install wxmac
```

and was able to get through the install with no issues.

Comment: When this came up 4 months ago it was clearly not working due to the different versions of various SDKs being incompatible.  I eventually went away from the idea of trying to compile anything and decided to only load binaries.  RapidSVN was not to be.  I'm now using Eclipse with the SVN plugin - it's working fine.